# How can I start the next matching activity if my app is the default one

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have an activity that works as a hook for various intents. Specifically, the VOICE_COMMAND and CALL_PRIVILEGED. (It is a requirement to use these.)

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I ask the user to set my app as the default action for these intents so they don't have to select it every time. This is also a requirement.

The problem is that in certain cases I want my activity to work transparently and pass the intent to the dialer or other app. This should be selectable by the user. I achieved this by using `getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(myCompName, isEnabled, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)` on my activity in certain places of the code.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I tried `startNextMatchingActivity(getIntent())` but that does not start anything (returns false). Does this mean that if there is a default action, then everything else is ignored from the intent resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (on Android 2.3) there seems to be no other way of forwarding the intent than doing it manually. Additionally, **to send CALL_PRIVILEGED intent the app must have special permissions that only system apps have**. (The app will receive not allowed exceptions otherwise.)

All in all, the intent must be converted to some other intent that my app can send and start the next activity manually by retrieving the list of applicable activities from the [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) API.